# Python ReportLab add rectangle

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to print the rectangle but I have no idea how to do it, this code works fine but I do not know how to append the rectangle.

I'll really appreciate any help.

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Flowable, Spacer
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()


draw = Drawing(500, 200)
draw.add(Rect(0, 100, 500, 100))

hola = ParagraphStyle('')
hola.fontSize = 9
hola.leading=0



story = []
        #add some flowables

story.append(Paragraph("This is a ",hola))
story.append(Spacer(0,20))
story.append(Paragraph(" <i>Normal</i> style.",hola))
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('mydoc.pdf',pagesize = letter)
doc.build(story)
```

Thank you !

Comment: I guess you forgot to append the drawing of rectangle into the story variable
`story = [draw]`

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to append your draw to your story:
  `story.append(draw)`